# PHP multiline string with PHP

Tags: php, html, multiline

I need to echo a lot of PHP and HTML.

I already tried the obvious, but it's not working:

```
<?php echo '
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {   ?>
      <div class="gridly-image"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('summary-image', array('class' => 'overlay', 'title'=> the_title('Read Article ',' now',false) ));?></a>
      </div>
      <?php }  ?>

      <div class="date">
      <span class="day">
        <?php the_time('d') ?></span>
      <div class="holder">
        <span class="month">
          <?php the_time('M') ?></span>
        <span class="year">
          <?php the_time('Y') ?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php }  ?>';
?>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you literally trying to echo PHP code?

Comment: well besides the obvious issues with the unescaped quotes you should als convert all < and > tags to their coresponding html code &lt; &gt;

Comment: Most people asking this question would be looking for HEREDOC. You may want to accept that answer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You don't need to output `php` tags:

```
<?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) 
    {
        echo '<div class="gridly-image"><a href="'. the_permalink() .'">'. the_post_thumbnail('summary-image', array('class' => 'overlay', 'title'=> the_title('Read Article ',' now',false) )) .'</a></div>';
    }

    echo '<div class="date">
              <span class="day">'. the_time('d') .'</span>
              <div class="holder">
                <span class="month">'. the_time('M') .'</span>
                <span class="year">'. the_time('Y') .'</span>
              </div>
          </div>';
?>
```

Comment: Internet, you surprise me every day :)*

Answer (score 61):

You cannot run PHP code within a string like that. It just doesn't work. As well, when you're "out" of PHP code (`?>`), any text outside of the PHP blocks is considered output anyway, so there's no need for the `echo` statement.

If you do need to do multiline output from with a chunk of PHP code, consider using a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc):

```
<?php

$var = 'Howdy';

echo <<<EOL
This is output
And this is a new line
blah blah blah and this following $var will actually say Howdy as well

and now the output ends
EOL;
```

Answer (score 24):

Use Heredocs to output muli-line strings containing variables. The syntax is...

```
$string = <<<HEREDOC
   string stuff here
HEREDOC;
```

The "HEREDOC" part is like the quotes, and can be anything you want. The end tag must be the only thing on it's line i.e. no whitespace before or after, and must end in a colon. For more info [check out the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Answer (score 5):

### Use the colon notation

Another option would be to use the `if` with a colon (`:`) and an `endif` instead of the brackets:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
    <div class="gridly-image">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('summary-image', array('class' => 'overlay', 'title'=> the_title('Read Article ',' now',false) )); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="date">
    <span class="day"><?php the_time('d'); ?></span>
    <div class="holder">
        <span class="month"><?php the_time('M'); ?></span>
        <span class="year"><?php the_time('Y'); ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The internal set of single quotes in your code is killing the string. Whenever you hit a single quote it ends the string and continues processing. You'll want something like:

```
$thisstring = 'this string is long \' in needs escaped single quotes or nothing will run';
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you must remove all `'` charachters in your string or use an escape character. Like:

```
<?php
    echo '<?php
              echo \'hello world\';
          ?>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `show_source();` function of PHP. Check for more details in *[show_source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.show-source.php)*. This is a better method I guess.