# Is it possible to have a PHP variable as a table?

Tags: php

Is it possible to define a variable in PhP as a table? ie

```
$table1 = <table style="width:100%">
               <tr>
                  <th>Firstname</th>
                  <th>Lastname</th> 
                  <th>Age</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Jill</td>
                   <td>Smith</td> 
                   <td>50</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td>Eve</td>
                    <td>Jackson</td> 
                    <td>94</td>
               </tr>
          </table>
;
```

Or is there a particuar way i can achieve the same?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? There are [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) which is the closest i can image to a table.

Comment: you need to store <table> into `''` then `echo $table1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multiline string with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534836/php-multiline-string-with-php)

Comment: Yes, because your "table" is just a text (string).

Comment: @DB i want dynamic table from a Mysql database

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mixing up two things:

- A list data structure where each element possesses the properties `firstname`, `lastname` and `age`.
- A way to represent the list, such as a table. In this case, a table in the markup language HTML.

You could use an `array()` with for each element an `array()` with key-value pairs in it. But it is better to apply an object-oriented approach.

You first need to construct objects of data from the database, and then populate an array with them:

```
class Person {

    private $firstname;
    private $lastname;
    private $age; // It's better to pass a birthdate.

    public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age) {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
}
```

```
$persons = array();

foreach ($someResultingRowFromDatabase as $row) {
    $persons[] = new Person($row['firstname'], $row['lastname'], $row['age']);
}
```

<sup>I don't know the exact code for fetching data from a database, but you should be using PDO.</sup>

And later walk over the `$persons` array with the `Person` objects and write the HTML table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Static table as PHP variable you can insert with in the single quote (`'`) like this code...

```
$table1 = '<table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th> 
                <th>Age</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson</td> 
                <td>94</td>
              </tr>
            </table>';
```

If you want dynamic table columns This code will work... Use concatenate Operator....

```
$table1 = '<table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th> 
            <th>Age</th>
          </tr>';
foreach($array as $val){
    $table1 .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$val['fname'].'</td>
                <td>'.$val['lname'].'</td> 
                <td>'.$val['age'].'</td>
              </tr>';
}
$table1 .= '</table>';
echo $table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is not called table, but an [Array](http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php). An Array is basically a set of data with an index. The data elements itself can be arrays again. Your structure itself would look like this as array:

```
$array = 
[
    [
        "Firstname" => "Jill",
        "Lastname" => "Smith",
        "Age" => 50
    ],
    [
        "Firstname" => "Eve",
        "Lastname" => "Jackson",
        "Age" => 94
    ],
];
```

You have now a variable, that contains your data in a structured form and you can loop through it using `for`or `foreach` loops. If your data is stored in a MySQL Databse, you might have a look at [this example on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php). This explains how to get data from you database to an array (not the `$actor` variable at the end of the example).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a heredoc string

```
 $table1 = <<<EOD
<table style="width:100%">
                              <tr>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th> 
                                <th>Age</th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Jill</td>
                                <td>Smith</td> 
                                <td>50</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Eve</td>
                                <td>Jackson</td> 
                                <td>94</td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
EOD;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$table1 = '<table style="width:100%">
               <tr>
                  <th>Firstname</th>
                  <th>Lastname</th> 
                  <th>Age</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Jill</td>
                   <td>Smith</td> 
                   <td>50</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td>Eve</td>
                    <td>Jackson</td> 
                    <td>94</td>
               </tr>
          </table>'
;

echo $table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You successfully did it!) U placed table to variable. But seriously you try to combine two things in one: data and view. It's a very wrong way in programing.